# perforce plugin eclipse unable to install

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, perforce, p4v

I want to install perforce plugin for eclipse 4.2 juno. On the site it states I need perforce v4.2. I have installed it, I can see the PV4 install - when going Help>about eclipse.

I can not see the perforce tab. Can not see the perspective view for it. When trying to import can not see anything perforce related. I have not used perfoce before, not sure what I am doing wrong. Any ideas?. (i tried to install perfoce v4.2,v3.7,v4.3,v4.4 . Reinstalled eclipse from 4.22 to 4.2 same issue.

Comment: If you do Window-->Open Perspective-->Other is it listed?

Comment: Have checked, no perforce is shown. The only reference to perforce that i see  is 'P4' being shown in about eclipse.